# send mail with uuencode

Tags: linux, unix, uuencode

hello I would like to send an email with attached a piece I try with the command uuencode but I have no mail in my mailbox that can help me please

```
cat body.txt | uuencode /root/report-20130322.pdf | mail -s "Daily Report" user@gmail.com
```

Comment: Do you really want to use uuencode in 2013? It's pretty well obsolete, you know. I checked my archives, and I haven't sent or received a single email using uuencode in almost 13 years.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, we won't help you use uuencode.  But we will recommend that you look at MIME instead.  It's the current standard for including non-textual data in email.  Whatever programming language you're using, there are many libraries to help you do it right.

Answer (score 0):

which file do you want to attach? pipes are from left to right so this is done first and it is illegal:

```
cat body.txt | uuencode /root/report-20130322.pdf
```

probably you can try

```
cat body.txt > tmpfile
uuencode /root/report-20130322.pdf >> tmpfile
cat tmpfile | mail -s "Daily Report" user@gmail.com
```